# Angular Drag Drop Resize With virtual Scroller

Tags: drag-and-drop, resize, angular6, amcharts4, virtualscroll

I am seeking assistance to identify a drag-and-drop, resize, and virtual scroller library compatible with the following Angular versions
  `"@angular/cdk": "^6.4.7", "@angular/common": "6.1.0", "@angular/compiler": "6.1.0", "@angular/core": "6.1.0",`
Specifically, I have a pop-up window containing more than six AmCharts charts that need to be made drag-and-drop and resizable. Due to the potential high volume of data, I aim to implement a virtual scroller within the pop-up to enhance the loading performance of the charts

I am expecting drag drop resizable virtual scroller lib compatible with above angular version